# get package name of apk file from path of application

Tags: android

I have one non activity class, in this class I have several apk file path like `/system/priv-app/TelephonyProvider/TelephonyProvider.apk`, Now from this file path I have to retrieve package name of apk files.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you probably will be unable to get that apk's info without root permissions, as it is a system app.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Thanks for response, I got solution posted below and it works for both system and non system app. Don't know first it was not working after cleaning and restarting studio it is giving me desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got the answer:

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, 0);
 String pkgName = info.packageName
```

Thanks all, Actually after cleaning project it works